# different version shown in properties of setup file and control panel

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

I have msi installer which is built using Wix Tools in Visual Studio 2012. 
I have set version of setup.exe using Version="(bind.FileVersion.File)". 
it looks good upto half way; means i get the same version displayed in Control 
Panel as the version of dll i have binded it to, after it has been installed.
But the problem is when i see the properties of setup.exe file it shows me 
different one.
Cant figure why this is happening?
Any help will be appreciated
Note I ma using 64-bit Windows 7 on 64-bit machine

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned an EXE rather than MSI I'm guessing that you are bundling your msi into a bootstrapper package.

To bind your exe version to your msi, use `bind.packageVersion.PackageID` as described [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html).

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" 
            Version="!(bind.PackageVersion.master)" 
            Manufacturer="Test" 
            UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef
            Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Id="master" SourceFile="MyInstaller.msi" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

To bind your MSI to your chosen assembly do the following:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">

  <Product Id="*"
           Name="MyProduct"
           Language="1033"
           Version="!(bind.fileVersion.My.dll)"
           Manufacturer="Test"
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
```

This should ensure the following binding order:

```
setup.exe -> install.msi -> assembly.dll
```

Comment: I have used this  Version="!(bind.fileVersion.My.dll)" and this shows correct version number in control panel, now what i actually want to do is to have (.msi and application.exe) both having the same version number (when inspected using right-click -> properties -> details) as application.exe shows in control panel.